# nodemailer transporter.templateSender function is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, email-templates

## Problem description

Hello, I am trying to use html templates using nodemailer's external renderer functionality. I therefore import nodemailer and EmailTemplates for my template engine that will be pug. I create my transporter with the due credentials. 
To create the template base sender function I have to use the transporter's templateSender function that apparently doesn't exist since I am getting an undefined function error. 
**Documentation Link for this process:** https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/templating/ 
Has anyone encountered the problem? Maybe it is an issue and if it is I will therefore submit an issue but I prefer checking if my code isn't the actual problem..

## Exisiting Code

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import EmailTemplate from "email-templates";

export default async function(userMail, typeOfMail, link) {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
    host: process.env.SMTP_SERVER_NAME,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
      pass: process.env.SMTP_PASS
    }
  });
  console.log(transporter.templateSender)
  const sendAccountValidation = transporter.templateSender(
    new EmailTemplate("../email_templates/account_validation"),
    {
      from: process.env.SMTP_USER
    }
  );
  sendPwdReminder(
    {
      to: "dest@email.com",
      subject: "subject"
    },
    function(err, info) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error");
      } else {
        console.log("Password reminder sent");
      }
    }
  );
}
```

## Error message

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: transporter.templateSender is not a function`

## Environment

- Docker
- nodemailer: "^6.2.1"
- email-templates: "^6.0.2"

Thanks for the help